# Create a table and add indexes in a single migration with Sequelize

Tags: indexing, migration, sequelize.js

What is the correct way to **create a table** and **add indices** on some of its columns in **a single migration**?

**Example Migration: 2012341234-create-todo.js**

How would I create an index on the "author_id" and "title" column?

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      author_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Authors',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'authorId'
        }
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },

      content: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Todos');
  }
};
```

The Sequelize docs indicate that an index would be added like this:

```
queryInterface.addIndex('Todos', ['author_id', 'title']);
```

Can these methods just be chained? Do "up" and "down" just need to return a promise? I'm not seeing anything in the docs about it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, the methods can be chained. In your case you just perform the `addIndex` after `createTable` method

```js
return queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
    // columns...
}).then(() => queryInterface.addIndex('Todos', ['author_id', 'title']))
.then(() => {
    // perform further operations if needed
});
```

Comment: If the .addIndex fails the .createTable will remain. This is not how to do migrations that have more than one step. See the answer that uses transactions.

Comment: ewww ... callback hell

Comment: how to defined BTREE and unique is false ?

Comment: check out second answer with transaction please

Answer (score 39):

The accepted solution is problematic if the second step fails. Transactions in each step should be used to allow a roll back to ensure all of the migration steps that are inserts or updates are undone if a problem is encountered at any step. For example:

```js
module.exports = {
 up: async (queryIntereface) => {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();

    try {
      await queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
        // columns...
      }, { transaction });
      await queryInterface.addIndex('Todos', ['author_id', 'title'], { transaction }));


      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface) {

    etc...
```

**Reference**

- https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#migration-skeleton (search for "transaction()"

Comment: Transactions won't help in certain databases such as MySQL where CREATE statements or ALTER TABLE which perform an implicit commit and cannot be rolled back. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Answer (score 9):

I didn't go with transactions. I just created the table and added the index in one step (unique index, which is what I needed):

```js
    'use strict';
    const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = {
      up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return await queryInterface.createTable('exampleTable', {
          id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
          },
          userId: {
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
              allowNull: false,
              references: {
                  model: 'user',
                  key: 'id'
              }
          },
          classId: {
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
              allowNull: false,
              references: {
                  model: 'class',
                  key: 'id'
              }
          },
      },
      {
          uniqueKeys: {
            unique_tag: {
                customIndex: true,
                fields: ["userId", "classId"]
            }
          }
        });
      },

      down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return await queryInterface.dropTable('exampleTable');
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

**Simplest way to add index**

```js
    'use strict';
    
    module.exports = {
      up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.addIndex('reports', ['client_id'])
          .then(() => {
            return queryInterface.addIndex('reports', ['report_name'])
          })
          .then(() => {
            return queryInterface.addIndex('reports', ['report_date'])
          })
      },
    
      down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.removeIndex('reports', ['client_id'])
        .then(() => {
          return queryInterface.removeIndex('reports', ['report_name'])
        })
        .then(() => {
          return queryInterface.removeIndex('reports', ['report_date'])
        })
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a whole new migration file using raw syntax

```
module.exports = {
 up: (queryInterface) => {
 return queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE INDEX devices_mac_uuid ON 
  "Devices" ("mac","uuid")')
 },
 down: (queryInterface) => {
  return queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP INDEX devices_mac_uuid')
 }
}
```

Comment: While your suggestion will work it does not answer the question of "the correct way". If you limit every migration to a single step you lose context as well as having an unnecessary number of files to process with every application build. The use of transactions allows for a safe multi-step migration. See transaction answer for an example.